# Gulp 3 to Gulp 4. Empty array in src and dest

Tags: html, web, gulp

could you please help me?
I'm woundering how can i migrate this to gulp 4.

```
pipe(gulp.dest(''));
gulp.src([])
```

This works in gulp 3 like a charm. But no in Gulp 4.

Comment: What should it do?

Comment: pipe(gulp.dest('')); This one should copy file into root folder. Where gulpfile.js exist.

Comment: Can you paste complete task code?

Comment: I have this same issue. Seems pretty dumb that `src()` cannot handle an empty array of globs. Our build script gets an array of globs from a config JSON that may be empty (which is perfectly valid) and Gulp 4 just crashes. Did you find anything out?

Answer (score 0):

As you have knew, `gulp.src` does not accept the empty array, herewith throws the unclear error. Thus you need to check the array for the elements count before invoke the `Gulp.dest`. If the array is empty, you can finish the task with `Gulp.src(".")`.